# Searching for the title of a Fantasy book series from the 1980's

Tags: story-identification, magical-transportation

I am trying to remember the name of a Fantasy series from the 1980's. It contained at least 7 novels.

I remember it was about a magic bottle that was entered by use of the ring. Each novel, whilst a separate story, was connected to the others, building the story of the bottle from different perspectives.

Went to re-read them but found they had been "tidied away" during a house move.

Any ideas on either title of the series or one of the books?

Comment: Note that there appears to be a deleted "thank you" answer that indicates the answer below is "spot on!"

Answer (score 3):

I think this is [Hugh Cook's Chronicles of an Age of Darkness](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chronicles_of_an_Age_of_Darkness).

Since that synopsis doesn't actually mention the bottle/ring elements, there's a note about it [here.](http://muleabides.wordpress.com/2009/10/01/magic-items-should-do-the-impossible/)